# How to spawn n processes and start another after one finishes using bash?

Tags: bash, process, jobs, pid

I'm trying to write a script that will run n number of processes in parallel which are forked from the main script.  The number of running processes should always be n, but the execution times per process may vary.

Example, I start three processes with pid's: 1, 2, and 3.  When one of the three processes ends, I'd like to start a new process. If 2 finishes first, I'll spawn off process 4 so the running pid's will be: 1, 3, and 4.

I've viewed other questions where the *wait* command is used until all the jobs have finished. In my case I do not want to have to wait until every job is done to continue, just when one of the running jobs finishes.

Comment: You can still use the wait command until one process is finsished, and then continue...

Comment: I was under the assumption that wait will block until all the processes have finished.

Comment: The `wait` builtin has multiple operation modes. Type `help wait` in bash

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `wait -n` option. Thanks @l'L'l and @hek2mgl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait -n `jobs -p`
```

Seems to do the job. Thanks for the guidance l'L'l and hek2mgl.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from just using wait etc, you can achieve powerful job control using gnu semaphore/parallel if you don't mind breaking out of pure bash builtins and installing a package.

```
# sem can emulate a counting semaphore. Use --jobs to set the number of toilets like this:

sem --jobs 3 --id my_id -u 'echo Start 1; sleep 5; echo 1 done' &&
sem --jobs 3 --id my_id -u 'echo Start 2; sleep 6; echo 2 done' &&
sem --jobs 3 --id my_id -u 'echo Start 3; sleep 7; echo 3 done' &&
sem --jobs 3 --id my_id -u 'echo Start 4; sleep 8; echo 4 done' &&
sem --wait --id my_id
```

> # Output:
>
> ```
> Start 1
> Start 2
> Start 3
> 1 done
> Start 4
> 2 done
> 3 done
> 4 done
> ```

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

It also has the power to control processes per CPU cores, specify timeouts for parallel processes etc